# Multiple App.config for Unit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, app-config

Im doing Unit tests for a big big project with so many things to test. My Project has 10 different modules.

Originally, I have my `App.config` where I have defined the path and the name of my `ModuleConfiguration.xml` and much more stuff... In this file, I have all the labels and values I use for these tests.
Until now, all OK.

But My `ModuleConfiguration` is getting really really big, so I decide to split up and have one `ConfigurationFile.xml` for every module...

So for example:

- **ModemModule**: `ModemConfiguration.xml`
- **HelperModule**: `HelperConfiguration.xml`
- and so on...

But then I would need one `App.config` for every different configurationFile as well...

So, my question is how I can use **multiple** `App.config` files in my proyect...

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Split the modules up into their own projects, then **Add As Link** the "main" App.config file:

[image: Sharing App.config across projects]

1. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer
2. Choose **Add** -> **Existing Item...**
3. Browse to the "main" project that contains the App.config you want to share with this project
4. Click the filetype dropdown filter and choose **All Files (*.*)**
5. Select the App.config
6. Click the little arrow next to the **Add** button and choose **Add As Link**

I already added App.config as a link to `Module01` in the screenshot. If you look closely, you'd notice the little shortcut overlay for Module01's App.config - that means that it's linked into the project from another project (in this case, the MyApplication project).

There are other ways to achieve what you want, but I believe this best fits your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Sammeer Singh, but spliting the modules into own proyects it is not possible... It´s just one single proyect.

Comment: Hmmm, well maybe you should consider it, since you mentioned in your question that there are lots of things to test and they are modularized.

Comment: That being said, have a look at the links posted by @Tobias. They might help you find the best solution to your problem.